# Is there a way to change the image position in UITabBar or UITabBarItem?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

So, I created the image too big for the TabBarItem, and parts of the image appear beyond the top of the TabBar

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcjvM.png)

I could:

1. Resize all the images in the Image.xassets
2. **Write a function to resize the image so it fits in the TabBarItem area**

I searched online but couldn't find a solution.
Is it possible to do No.2? Thanks!

Comment: https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

Comment: Pls read [https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in HIG (Apple Human Interface Guidelines) size of tab bar icons should be **69px × 69px (23pt × 23pt @3x)** in regular mode and **51px × 51px (17pt × 17pt @3x)** for compact mode. I suggest solution number one and resize all tab bar images.

You can read more in HIG:

> https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

Comment: Thanks! I guess I will have to follow the Apple Guideline then. Will spend time resizing them. Thanks!